# browser-side pre upload image scaling and cropping reliability and security

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing

I like to give users of a website the ability to crop the image before the upload. This is convenient for those not knowing image manipulation tools, and may greatly reduce the upload time, as the uploaded image is quite small compared to the usual digital camera image used as source.

I would like to use the HTML5 File API, img-Tag, canvas-Element and FormData API to decode, manipulate and upload the image.

I wonder if there are security and reliability implications about this. Loading a large image may break client side DOM or JavaScript and crash the page or the whole browser. What would be the largest images one can to expect to be handled by JavaScript (eg. loaded and resized)? Does the browser recognize any format despite JPG and PNG (eg TIFF) ?

Malicious code inside image files may access JavaScript somehow and abuse the user's session credentials. Does this pose any practial risk?

Answer (score 1):

i also have this problem a year age, so i decided to create my own php and jquery script that would do the cropping and resizing with both client side and server side validation, so that if user use any tricks the server will choose the default option rather that client side:

so how do we do that first of all we need client side form for cropping and resizing and blah blah...... so we need jquery there is a excellent plugin for that: **jquery image are select**

and then we need to retrieve the value of the cropping so the server can be sure that the user is not tricking or spamming or hacking.

an excellent php library is php gd library it should come with latest php versions, but you may need to enable the extension just search on google and you will find out how to enable them.

now the gd library would catch the axis and crop it on **serverside** not client side. client will only provide the info of how much it should crop and the server will do the job :)

**here is a script i write a year ago. it is a little bit messy(html and css). but it should do the job.**
[image cropping and uploading tool php jquery](http://1drv.ms/1egTg5p)

**note:** *you will need to enable gd extension in order for this work, try it on your local server. after enabling the extension you will need to restrat the server and run the script. it should run out of the box, but tell me if something didn't work or errors:)*